# Error with a defined variable for an actionmap in Unity c# (using the InputSystem)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm having this problem I can't figure out that involves Unity's InputSystem. I was wondering if anyone had a solution. So basically I have a script, Player, that handles most of my input system stuff with the action map. However, there's a few instances where I have to use a different script and I get odd bugs.

Sp Player has this (among other code):

```
public PlayerControls playerControls { get; private set; }

public void OnEnable()
{

    playerControls.Enable();
}

public void OnDisable()
{

    playerControls.Disable();

}


public void Awake()
{

    playerControls = new PlayerControls();

}
```

There there's a script currently that goes on objects that the player can use an interact button with, which has this:

```
public PlayerControls playerControls;

Debug.Log("heroScript variable in ObjectInteraction is set to " + heroScript);
playerControls = heroScript.playerControls;

Debug.Log("playerControls is " + playerControls.ToString());
playerControls.PlayerActions.Interact.performed += InteractWithObject;
```

The two images have the error readout I get on play as well as what is assigned in the script in unity.

[Bug readout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIXAu.png)

[Script field on the object it is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Ajb.png)

I've gone in circles trying to fix this and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, you can see that the debug.log finds the value of the variable, but I'm still erroring out when it is being set.

Also, line 69 is

```
playerControls = heroScript.playerControls;
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

For those that are having the same issue that stumble on this, it seems like you do have to run everything through a "parent" script that is the one that declares the action map with the line:

```
yourActionMapVariableHere = new YourActionMapNameHere();
```

Any other scripts that need to use the action map will have to be filtered through that primary script. The people that have helped me that are familiar with the InputSystem in Unity have not been able to give me an answer on a way to do otherwise, and I am pretty sure you don't want to generate multiple versions of the same action map, though I do not actually know what the consequences of that could be.